# allow index.php only on subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I have a website on a domain.
And another website on a subdomain (which points to a folder).

I get this error as I try to reach the website on the subdomain:
**strong text**
**Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /index.php on this server.**

In the htaccess of the **main-website** I see this code to remove the index.php to make the url clean:

```
#### remove index.php ##########################
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^POST
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php(.*)\ HTTP/ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(.*)$ http:\/\/www.mainsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But on a website that can be reached via **subdomain**
with data within a **subfolder**,
. . .
**I seem to need the index.php ( right ? )**

So the question is:
How can I allow **index.php** requests just for the **subfolder / subdomain ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `RewriteCond` in your rule to target only one particular domain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mainsite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /(.*)index\.php(.*)\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^index\.php(.*)$ http://www.mainsite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```